# MySQL - Nested loops count too high resulting in query taking too long

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am seeing high response time for a MySQL query. I have two similar queries:

```
SELECT `orders`.`id` FROM `orders` WHERE (`orders`.line_count = 0 OR
                  `orders`.account_type_id IS NULL OR
                  `orders`.account_type_id IN (NULL)
                     OR `orders`.id IN (
                      SELECT lines.order_id from lines
                      INNER JOIN (select sec_accounts.id from accounts sec_accounts
                      WHERE (sec_accounts.account_type_id = 344 AND ((`sec_accounts`.`segment_1` = 'MS')))
                      ) as sec_accounts2 ON sec_accounts2.id = lines.account_id
                      WHERE lines.allocation_count = 0
                    )
) ORDER BY `orders`.`id` ASC LIMIT 90;
```

**This took `90 rows in set (6.23 sec)` to complete**

```
SELECT `orders`.`id` FROM `orders` WHERE (`orders`.line_count = 0 OR
                  `orders`.account_type_id IS NULL OR
                  `orders`.account_type_id IN (NULL)
                     OR `orders`.id IN (
                      SELECT lines.order_id from lines
                      INNER JOIN (select sec_accounts.id from accounts sec_accounts
                      WHERE (sec_accounts.account_type_id = 8 AND ((`sec_accounts`.`segment_1` = '2D')))
                      ) as sec_accounts2 ON sec_accounts2.id = lines.account_id
                      WHERE lines.allocation_count = 0
                    )
) ORDER BY `orders`.`id` ASC LIMIT 90;
```

**And this took `90 rows in set (0.05 sec)` to complete**

Notice, the difference between these two queries is just in the `WHERE` condition.

However, I was expecting the first query to be faster.
First query subquery is returning `101101` records and second subquery is returning `923113` records i.e **9x of first subquery**

Also, the where condition on accounts table returns `5648` and `175667` for first and second query respectively.

And still first query is very very slow as compared to second query which is strange.

I then started debugging this using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and these are the details:

```
Limit: 90 row(s)  (cost=0.43 rows=90) (actual time=1568.991..7802.360 rows=90 loops=1)
    -> Filter: ((orders.line_count = 0) or (orders.account_type_id is null) or (orders.account_type_id = NULL) or <in_optimizer>(orders.id,<exists>(select #2)))  (cost=0.43 rows=90) (actual time=1568.991..7802.349 rows=90 loops=1)
        -> Index scan on orders using PRIMARY  (cost=0.43 rows=90) (actual time=0.038..263.263 rows=443352 loops=1)
        -> Select #2 (subquery in condition; dependent)
            -> Limit: 1 row(s)  (cost=1.53 rows=0) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=0 loops=443348)
                -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=1.53 rows=0) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=0 loops=443348)
                    -> Filter: ((lines.allocation_count = 0) and (lines.account_id is not null))  (cost=0.97 rows=2) (actual time=0.008..0.011 rows=4 loops=443348)
                        -> Index lookup on lines using index_ol_on_order_id_supplier_id_reporting_total (order_id=<cache>(orders.id))  (cost=0.97 rows=3) (actual time=0.007..0.011 rows=4 loops=443348)
                    -> Filter: ((sec_accounts.account_type_id = 344) and (sec_accounts.segment_1 = 'MS'))  (cost=0.25 rows=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1571833)
                        -> Single-row index lookup on sec_accounts using PRIMARY (id=lines.account_id)  (cost=0.25 rows=1) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1571833)
```

```
Limit: 90 row(s)  (cost=0.43 rows=90) (actual time=1.893..78.997 rows=90 loops=1)
    -> Filter: ((orders.line_count = 0) or (orders.account_type_id is null) or (orders.account_type_id = NULL) or <in_optimizer>(orders.id,<exists>(select #2)))  (cost=0.43 rows=90) (actual time=1.892..78.985 rows=90 loops=1)
        -> Index scan on orders using PRIMARY  (cost=0.43 rows=90) (actual time=0.020..3.054 rows=3634 loops=1)
        -> Select #2 (subquery in condition; dependent)
            -> Limit: 1 row(s)  (cost=1.53 rows=0) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=0 loops=3634)
                -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=1.53 rows=0) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=0 loops=3634)
                    -> Filter: ((lines.allocation_count = 0) and (lines.account_id is not null))  (cost=0.97 rows=2) (actual time=0.010..0.014 rows=3 loops=3634)
                        -> Index lookup on lines using index_ol_on_order_id_supplier_id_reporting_total (order_id=<cache>(orders.id))  (cost=0.97 rows=3) (actual time=0.009..0.013 rows=3 loops=3634)
                    -> Filter: ((sec_accounts.account_type_id = 8) and (sec_accounts.segment_1 = '2D'))  (cost=0.26 rows=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=10679)
                        -> Single-row index lookup on sec_accounts using PRIMARY (id=lines.account_id)  (cost=0.26 rows=1) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=10679)
```

And no. of loops for first subquery is `443348` and for second subquery is `3634` which is strange to me.

Why is no. of loops so high for first query and any other reason why is it so slow?

Comment: General thought: avoid using `IN SELECT` and use `JOIN`s instead

Comment: "First query subquery" -- Meaning _textually_ first (IN(SELECT..)) or executionally? (JOIN(SELECT...))?

Comment: Would you also provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`  (Yeah, it provide less info, but it might be more obvious what the difference is.)

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I see is in the values for account_type_id and segment_1.  So, I deduce that the slow run had a lot more rows to check.

Try adding these composite indexes:

```
orders:  INDEX(line_count, account_type_id, id)
sec_accounts:  INDEX(account_type_id, segment_1,  id)
lines:  INDEX(account_id, allocation_count,  order_id)
```

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.
That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.

Probably turning `IN ( SELECT ... )` into a `JOIN` would help.  (But I am not sure.)

Comment: MySQL isn't picking up these indexes unless i use force index which i am reluctant to do.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT...` and the new CREATE TABLE` -- I may spot something I missed.  You could manually use FORCE INDEX to test them.